# Probability of meeting using integral

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Here is a famous question- Two people agree to meet sometime between 9am and 10am. Each picks a time uniformly and waits for 15 minutes. What is the probability that they meet?

I know that this can be easily tackled by drawing rectangles. The problem eventually boils down to finding the probability of the event $|X-Y|<0.25$ where X and Y are uniform random variables. I would like to understand how to proceed through integration. Here is what I have
$$P(|X-Y|<0.25) = 2P(X-Y<0.25) = 2\int P(X<0.25+y)f_Y(y)dy $$
I am confused what would be the limit of the integral. I have used convolution and symmetry, and assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Are the assumptions correct? How to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Before we even reach the integral, the equation $$P(|X-Y|<0.25) = 2P(X-Y<0.25)$$ is false.

Comment: Could you explain why? I don't see it. That absolute value is symmetric right?

Comment: You cannot simply say "It's symmetric" and then do whatever you want.  You have two facts: (1) $y = |x|$ is symmetric about $x=0$ and (2) the distribution of $X-Y$ is symmetric about $0$.  Together, this means you can break $|X-Y| < 0.25$ into two equally likely disjoint cases: $-0.25 < X-Y < 0$ and $0 < X-Y < 0.25$ (here, note $X-Y=0$ has probability zero, so it's ignored).  Therefore we can say $$P(|X-Y| < 0.25) = 2P(0 < X-Y < 0.25)$$
Without that $0$, your result would have ended up greater than $1$.

Comment: As a final point, I assume your error in intuition came from looking at the **true** equation $$P(|X-Y| > 0.25) = 2P(X-Y > 0.25)$$ and then incorrectly thinking it holds similarly for $<$.  However, when dealing with $|X-Y| > 0.25$ the symmetry gives the equally likely disjoint cases $X-Y > 0.25$ and $X-Y < -0.25$, which is why we seemingly can just drop the absolute value and put a $2$ outside the probability _in this case_.  In both circumstances, note that we might say "By symmetry" in the final proof, but we can always check what exactly the symmetry gives us, and we should do so.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you for the wonderful explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to understand how to proceed through integration

$$1-2\int_0^{\frac{3}{4}}\Bigg[\int_{x+\frac{1}{4}}^1dy\Bigg]dx=\frac{7}{16}$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain it? Where did the 2 come from. I think I get the logic of limits.

Comment: @ForumWhiner :  simply I did the drawing  you know...then I integrated the interested area...it is easy to integrate the complement. 2 is because there are two identical triangles to integrate

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @ForumWhiner : added a drawing...just in case